# Pass class type as param

Tags: java

Pass a type as a parameter to an api

Comment: You can take a look at Java generics, that might help solve your problem https://www.baeldung.com/java-generics

Comment: You can do this but not in the way you describe here.  Depending on what you need this for, there are several ways to approach it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can receive Class as a parameter, like below,

```
 buildCriteriaQ(Class<?> parentClass) {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = factory.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery(entityClass);
        Root<?> a = cq.from(entityClass);
        cq.select(a);

        Query query = factory.createEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        List results = query.getResultList();
        System.out.println(results);
    }
```

and call this method like below,

`buildCriteriaQ(Item.class);`

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use **reflection** to make an instance of an object from `Class` type

eg.

```
    Class clazz = ... //your class
    Constructor constructor = clazz.getConstructor(prepareParameterTypes(parameters));
    constructor.newInstance(parameters);
```